# chrome tool for debugging android devices

Tags: remote-debugging

I am trying to use the chrome remote devices debugging tool.
I followed the steps in this guide:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

But I can't see my device on the list.
My device is Xiaomi mi 10.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?